# Auto adjust HTML/CSS content on screen depending on resolution of screen?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010

I have created one HTML design containing rectangular boxes on hover of which it displays content. It looks proper on my screen (1600x900) but on bigger screens like 1900x1080 design gets displaced.

What I have tried:

I tried viewport

but it doesn't work.

max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;

even this didn't work.

P.S: we do not have responsive UI for our website.

Any solution or guidance will much appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mandar

Comment: Depends so much on how you have structured your html/css. If you have specified fixed pixel widths for your rectangular box elements, it will never scale how you want. It soubds like you need to scale using percentages, with perhaps a fixed minimum width.

Comment: Have you added viewport meta tag?